# compiling in Visual Studio vs. compiling with cl in the command line

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, compilation, cl

I have a script for testing C programs in a university course. I compile the students' files using the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 by simply running the command `cl file.c`. However, I found out that in some (pretty rare) cases, I get different outputs for those programs comparing to running them on VS2015 (we guide our students to check their programs in that IDE). *After some investigation I found that it happens when I include a header (.h) file* (see the code example below).

Is `cl` actually the same compiler that VS2015 uses? if it is - then how come I get different results. If not - what command should I give in order to get similar results?

Code example - a program that runs a functions that should evaluate a math-string. The evaluation is done from left-to-right, regardless of the ordinary math order precedence:

## test_data.h

```
#ifndef _TEST_DATA_H
#define _TEST_DATA_H

char *mathString2 = "64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8";

#endif /* _TEST_DATA_H */
```

## test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_data.h"

// Q1
double string2uint(char str[])
{
    int i = 0;
    double res = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        res = res * 10 + (str[i] - '0');
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}

void calcMathString(char mathString[])
{
    int i, j = 0;
    double e = 0;
    char t = '+', str_n[101];
    for (; mathString[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        i = 0;
        while (mathString[j] != '\0') {
            str_n[i] = mathString[j];
            if (mathString[j] == ' ')
            {
                str_n[i] = '\0';
                i++;
                j++;
                break;
            }
            if (mathString[j + 1] == '\0')
            {
                i++;
                str_n[i] = '\0';
                j++;
                break;
            }
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (t == '+') {
            e = e + string2uint(str_n);
        }
        if (t == '-') {
            e = e - string2uint(str_n);
        }
        if (t == '*') {
            e = e*string2uint(str_n);
        }
        if (t == '/') {
            e = e / string2uint(str_n);
        }
        t = mathString[j];
        j = j + 1;
    }
    printf("%s = %.3lf\n", mathString, e);
}

int main()
{
    char *mathString1 = "64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8";
    calcMathString(mathString1);
    calcMathString(mathString2);
    return 0;
}
```

note that `mathString1, mathString2` are identical.
The output I get compiling with `cl`:

```
64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8 = 56.000
64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8 = 48.000
```

The output I get when running it in VS:

```
64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8 = 56.000
64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8 = 56.000
```

Comment: The VS has a load of project settings which you might want to mimic by specific `cl` parameters to get the exact same binary.

Comment: How can I know those parameters? I would like the my command line `cl` compilation to behave like the VS does.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter, as having different results is pointing to some undefined behavior in your code, which should be fixed.

Comment: Try `char *mathString2 = "64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8\0" "1111";` to see that code is accessing out of bounds.

Comment: `if (mathString[j + 1] == '\0')` that could access outside the string since previous instruction increments `j` already. End your string with a space you could have this issue.

Comment: also you're incrementing `j` in the `for` loop and also _inside_ the loop!!

Comment: "I get different outputs for those programs" is because code attempts to access beyond the two `"64 / 8 * 8 - 8 / 8 / 8 / 8 * 8 * 8 * 8"` _string literals_ which have different data after them.  Re-write to only access within array bounds to remove the _undefined behavior_.

Comment: "what command should I give in order to get similar results?" Catching UB is tricky.  Could use a string literal like `"64 / 8\0+ 42\0\0\0\0"` or arrays with random sentinels.  But UB is UB - sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: thanks for you comments. So you guys imply that it happens due to some code error? Still, I just can't get it - no matter whether the code is good or not (it's a student's code btw) - how come the results are different depending on where I compiled the code?

Answer (score 0):

VS runs the same cl.exe compiler as you get from the command prompt, however building in VS will almost certainly pass far more command line arguments.

Using "msbuild" from the command line would produce the same build sequence that VS would use.

Comment: `msbuild` cannot compile a single .c file directly. As far as I understand - it compiles VS project files (right?). If that's the case - it won't help me